# "Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at…" error using pywinauto and wmi

Tags: python, wmi, pywinauto

- Python: 3.7.2 64 Bit
- comtypes: 1.1.7
- pywin32: 224
- pywinauto: 0.6.6
- wmi: 1.4.9

Example 1:

```
import pywinauto
print('Test Imports')
```

Result 1:

```
Test Imports
```

Example 2:

```
import wmi
print('Test Imports')
```

Result 2:

```
Test Imports
```

Example 3:

```
import wmi, pywinauto
print('Test Imports')
```

Result 3:

```
Test Imports
Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at 0xa0695ec0
```

Example 4:

```
import pywinauto, wmi
print('Test Imports')
```

Result 4:

```
Test Imports
Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at 0x92e03a28
Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at 0x90680bf8
Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at 0x9312bc98
```

Also using `import sys; sys.coinit_flags = 0` doesn't help.